# How to use an alternative library outside of linux system

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

I'm build an opensourced project configured by GNU autoconf. It depends on the glib2.36 and it reports the glib library's version is lower than that. But I don't want to replace my system's glib in the path of "/usr/lib". My idea is to download the glib2.36 and build from scratch and install it to "$HOME/local". Then I want to configure the project using --prefix=$HOME/local.

```
    $cd ~/tmp/glib-2.36.0$
    $./configure  --prefix=$HOME/local
    $make
    $make install

    $cd ~/tmp/project
    $./configure --prefix=$HOME/local
```

but it still reports "checking for GLIB - version >= 2.36.0... no"
How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your project uses pkg-config and the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro, you can check where pkg-config looks for `.pc` files with: `pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config`

You can specify paths for pkg-config to search *first* by setting the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable. So, you would invoke configure with something like:

`env PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/local/pkgconfig" ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local`

Answer (score 1):

`--prefix` does't specify where ./configure looks for library. It sets where to install files when you run `make install`. `./configure --help` will show you more options.

If pkg-config is used you cant set `GLIB_CFLAGS` and `GLIB_LIBS` env variables to change path for specific package.

But you would check `./configure --help` first.